# Non standard rails routes in used in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, view-helpers

In my routes.rb there is

```
resources :clients_assessments do
  member do
    get :medical_edit
    get :mental_health_edit
    get :personal_edit
  end
  collection do
  end
end
```

Which gives routes

```
         medical_edit_clients_assessment GET    /clients_assessments/:id/medical_edit(.:format)       {:action=>"medical_edit", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
   mental_health_edit_clients_assessment GET    /clients_assessments/:id/mental_health_edit(.:format) {:action=>"mental_health_edit", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
        personal_edit_clients_assessment GET    /clients_assessments/:id/personal_edit(.:format)      {:action=>"personal_edit", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
                     clients_assessments GET    /clients_assessments(.:format)                        {:action=>"index", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
                                         POST   /clients_assessments(.:format)                        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
                  new_clients_assessment GET    /clients_assessments/new(.:format)                    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
                 edit_clients_assessment GET    /clients_assessments/:id/edit(.:format)               {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
                      clients_assessment GET    /clients_assessments/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
                                         PUT    /clients_assessments/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"update", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
                                         DELETE /clients_assessments/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
```

When I try to use them in a helper file like

```
route = medical_edit_clients_assessment_path(id)
```

An error message is generated

```
No route matches {:action=>"medical_edit", :controller=>"clients_assessments"}
```

I have to change it to

```
route = "/clients_assessment/#{able_id}/medical_edit"
```

to get around the error message. What is funny though that a route like

```
route = (able_id.nil? ? new_client_path : edit_client_path(able_id))
```

works just fine.

I know someone one will ask for it so here is the entire routes.rb and the result of the rake routes

https://gist.github.com/3074287

Thanks, Russ

Comment: please post content of `params[]` Hash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happened because id is nil

Comment: This code suddenly started working, it probably was some bad data.